# PHPexcel generated CSV for values not set (each row with diff. no. of col's)

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

Generated CSV file using below code

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex( 0 )
                ->setCellValue( 'A1', 'one' )
                ->setCellValue( 'B1', 'two' )
                ->setCellValue( 'C1', 'three' );
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex( 0 )
                    ->setCellValue( 'A2', 'mon' )
                    ->setCellValue( 'B2', 'tue' )
                    ->setCellValue( 'C2', 'wed' )
                    ->setCellValue( 'D2', 'thu' )
                    ->setCellValue( 'E2', 'fri' );
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV')->setUseBOM(TRUE)
                                                                ->setDelimiter(',')
                                                                ->setEnclosure('')
                                                                ->setSheetIndex(0)
                                                                ->save('php://output');
```

So the above code generating results. But i don't want comma to generate for **D1 & E1** cells.

> **Would like to get result as :**
>
> ---
>
> one,two,three
>
> ---
>
> mon,tue,wed,thu,fri
>
> ---

is there a way for define PHPExcel to read on each rows?

Comment: [github issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/150) somehow found this link! but not sure how to implement it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ended up by writing my own class [github](https://github.com/syednizamudeen/CSVwriter)